# Excel VBA ByVal Target As Range Does not update Target Worksheet when excuting from a function cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a issues with copying a value from a cell that is using a function to get its value from another cell. Insert value into A1, A3=A1 and when ever the value of A3 changes the changes need to transfer automatically to column H. The issues i having is that if i type the value into A1 then A3 gets updated but the values do not transfer over, if i type the value into A3 then the H column does update.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("A3").Address Then

    ' Get the last row on our destination sheet (using Sheet2, col A here)...
    Dim intLastRow As Long
    intLastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Add our value to the next row...
    Sheet1.Cells(intLastRow + 1, "H") = Target.Value

End If

End Sub
```

Please see image[image: Screenshot of sheet]

I have also tried the following code.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

None of the above seems to trigger of the change event. Please I can not use Value A1 for the Value change it has come from A3 value change. I have even thought of running a copy and paste macro to Trigger A3. But would really like the value change code to work i can get the change value to work from A3. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheet_Change` does not fire when a cell recalculates its formula. It fires when a cell's `Value` is assigned.

If you are assigning a value to `A1`, you should be looking at `Range("A1").Address` in your handler.

The are several `Calculate` events, but they fire when calculation is complete for the entire sheet, not for individual cells.

Comment: Hi there GSerg. A1 is data pulled via the web. Even if i did run it on A1 it also dose not trigger the event

Comment: If it's pulled with a macro, it will trigger the event unless you have manually disabled events (in which case you want to not disable them). If it's pulled with a web query, you want to handle the Refresh event of the query table.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling events while processing your `Change`. Your code might be getting itself in a loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Address = Range("A3").Address Then

    ' Get the last row on our destination sheet (using Sheet2, col A here)...
    Dim intLastRow As Long
    intLastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Add our value to the next row...
    Sheet1.Cells(intLastRow + 1, "H") = Target.Value

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script will run every time the calculation on the sheet is finished, for more info see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-calculate-event-excel) and it will then update `Colunm H` with the value in `A3`.

Not sure if it is exactly what will help but might get you on the right path. You can also build a check in to verify if the new `A3` value is the same at the last `Column H` value and if they are then you could bypass the inserting of the value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()

    ' Get the last row on our destination sheet (using Sheet2, col A here)...
    Dim intLastRow As Long
    intLastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Add our value to the next row...
    Sheet1.Cells(intLastRow + 1, "H") = Sheet1.Range("A3").Value

End Sub
```