# Reading a formula output

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA

I need to unhide/hide a row on a different page depending on a value. The issue I'm having is the value is formula driven and is not getting picked up by my VBA code. What changes need to be made so it will read the formula value?

Any guidance or advise would be greatly appreciated.

This is what is meant to trigger the Macro:

```vb
If Target.Address(False, False) = "K20" And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    Call ShowxxxResults
Else
End If

If Target.Address(False, False) = "K20" And Target.Value = "No" Then
    Call HidexxxResults
Else
End If
```

Here is the Macros they call to:

```vb
Sub ShowxxxResults()
    With Sheets("Results")
        Sheets("Results").Unprotect ("xxx")
        .Range("A44", "A45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Results").Protect ("xxx")
    End With
End Sub

Sub HidexxxResults()
    With Sheets("Results")
        Sheets("Results").Unprotect ("xxx")
        .Range("A44", "A45").EntireRow.Hidden = True        
        Sheets("Results").Protect ("xxx")
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: `the value is formula driven and is not getting picked up by my VBA code` - [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48028941/11683)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you [don't have to unprotect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453611/vba-excel-how-do-i-use-a-function-as-a-parameter#comment93779918_53453611) each time.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different method, Instead of trying to pick up the formula value I instead calculated the result in VBA

```
If Range("K44") = "Yes" And Range("K46") = "Yes" And Range("K50") = "No" And Range("K52") = "No" And Range("K54") = "No" And Range("K56") = "No" And Range("K58") = "No" And Range("K60") = "No" And Range("K62") = "No" Or Range("K44") = "Yes" And Range("K48") = "Yes" And Range("K50") = "No" And Range("K52") = "No" And Range("K54") = "No" And Range("K56") = "No" And Range("K58") = "No" And Range("K60") = "No" And Range("K62") = "No" Then

        Call ShowEBAResult

      Else
End If
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score -1):

I tried the code with K20 generated by formula and it worked for me. My suggestion would be to change it to

```
If Target.Address(False, False) = "K20" Then
    If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
            ShowxxxResults
        ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
            HidexxxResults
    End If
End If
```

and step through it to see where it breaks down. Put a watch on Target.Value and see if indeed the expression value is "Yes" or "No".

Comment: The point of the question is that this code, which is in `Worksheet_Change`, does not trigger when the formula in K20 recalculates. `Worksheet_Change` does not fire on formula calculations.